# Incorrect output from file

Tags: c, file, file-handling, tdm-gcc

I am trying to input some data into a file and then read and print it on the console.

Here is my code:

```
  fp=fopen("user1","w+");
  char line[1000];
  char *c;
  //write on file

  while(1)
  {
      fgets(line,sizeof(line),stdin);
      if(strcmp(line,":wq\n")==0)   //input ends when user enters :wq
          break;
      else
          fputs(line,fp);
  }
  //read from file
  fflush(stdin);

  while(1)
  {
      c=fgetc(fp);
      if(c==EOF)
          break;
      else
          printf("%ch",c);
   }
```

I input the data as

bjsa

:wq

The output:

```
 h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h  h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h
```

What is the problem?

Comment: I think you mean `printf("%c", c)`, that's why you're getting a lot of h's in the output.

Comment: The first problem is that you didn't post the full code. Don't make us guess if you want a good answer.

Comment: I posted the part of the code which was relevant for the above problem.Posting the full code will just distract focus from the actual problem and mess things up.

Comment: writing printf("%c",c) helped.It was my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems

1) Your `fgetc` assigns to a char point. That is wrong. It shall be an int

2) After writing the file, you should close it and then open it for reading

Something like:

```
  fp=fopen("user1","w+");
  char line[1000];
  int c;             // notice ......

  //write on file    
  while(1)
  {
      fgets(line,sizeof(line),stdin);
      if(strcmp(line,":wq\n")==0)   //input ends when user enters :wq
          break;
      fputs(line,fp);
  }
  fclose(fp);


  //read from file
  fp=fopen("user1","r");
  while(1)
  {
      c=fgetc(fp);
      if(c==EOF)
          break;
      printf("%ch",c);
  }
  fclose(fp);
```

Comment: You must check the return value of `fgets()`. You should avoid infinite loops; test `fgets()` in the first loop condition, and the result of the assignment and comparison in the second.

Comment: closing and opening the file helped.I had forgotten that writing to file moves pointer down till the last write location.This explains why I was getting so many 'h'.

Comment: Can you tell why you used int type in c?

Comment: @SarthakMehra - `fgetc` returns an int - see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html - the reason is that EOF is a negative value.